# SVG line animation

Tags: html, svg, css-animations

I am trying to use this trick to animate an svg picture:

http://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

Here I created a codepen with my own version, but no matter what I do I can't seem to make it work. As far as I can see the only difference between my version and the one on css tricks is that I am using line elements instead of paths.

http://codepen.io/webconsult/pen/HgIsk

Additionally, can someone tell me how to accomplish this without using an inline svg?

CSS:

```
svg {
  width: 100%;
}
svg .line {
  stroke-dasharray: 1300;
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
}
@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1300;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="1920px" height="640px" viewBox="0 0 1920 640" enable-background="new 0 0 1920 640" xml:space="preserve">
  <line class="line" fill="none" stroke="#8FB6D0" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="640" y1="482" x2="-1" y2="482"/>
  <line class="line" fill="none" stroke="#8FB6D0" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="640" y1="482" x2="-1" y2="482"/>
  [...]
  <line class="line" fill="none" stroke="#8FB6D0" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="640" y1="482" x2="-1" y2="482"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Good spotted. They mention that in the article, I only checked that the stroke color was there. I added it now, but it still does not work.

Comment: try "-webkit-animation" and "@-webkit-keyframes".

Comment: Yay, that did the trick. I already tried browser-prefixing animation, but not @keyframes. Thanks! Post as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On chrome (or other), css animation needs to be written with vender prefix yet.
So, you should rewrite the code like this.

```
svg {
  width: 100%;
}
svg .line {
  stroke-dasharray: 1300;
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
  -webkit-animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
}
@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1300;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1300;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```